# Access query to find special characters

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table and want to make a query which will give all the records which has s   - Invoice # field with special characters like ., ,, -, !, ~, etc. and also small letter alphabets

I am using below code but still it shows all the alphabets instead only lower alphabets

```
SELECT * 
FROM eForm 
WHERE ((((Audit.INV) Like "[\,/,+,,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,,(,),_,-,+,=,[,.{,},;,:,', ,,<,>,.,`,~,/,?,\,|,a, ]")));
```

Comment: My code is " SELECT *
FROM eForm
WHERE ((((Audit.INV) Like "*[\,/,+,*,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),_,-,+,=,[,.{,},;,:,', ,,<,>,.,`,~,/,?,\,|,a, ]*")));   "

Comment: You can't use LIKE for case-sensitive matching. [The Microsoft Jet (and ACE) database engine is inherently case-insensitive.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33553217/3820271)

Comment: Should i use StrComp(INV, 0) = 0